# How to execute an update via SQLQuery in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-update

I need to update a joined sub-class. Since Hibernate doesn't allow to update joined sub-classes in hql or named-query I want to do it via SQL. I also can't use a sql named-query because updates via named-query are not supported in Hibernate.

So I decided to use a SQLQuery. But Hibernate complaints about not calling addScalar():

> org.hibernate.QueryException: addEntity() or addScalar() must be called on a sql query before executing the query.

Are updates returning the number of rows affected and how is named that column?

Are there any other ways to do an update on a joined sub-class in hibernate?

Here is a brief example of what i'm trying to do:

```
<hibernate-mapping>  
        <class name="example.NiceClass" table="NICE_CLASS">  
  <meta attribute="class-code"></meta>  
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">  
   <column name="NICE_CLASS_ID" precision="8" />  
   <generator class="sequence">  
    <param name="sequence">NICE_CLASS_SEQ</param>  
   </generator>  
  </id>  
    </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>      
<hibernate-mapping package="example">  
    <joined-subclass name="SubJoinedClass" table="SUB_JOINED_CLASS"
     extends="NiceClass">  
        <key column="NICE_CLASS_ID" foreign-key="NICE_JOINED_ID_FK"/>  
  <property name="name" type="string" not-null="false">  
   <column name="NAME" >  
    <comment>name</comment>  
   </column>  
  </property>  
         </joined-subclass>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance!

So I want to do a:

```
update SubJoinedClass set name = 'newName'
```

Comment: can youe explain what query you would like to perform on the joined sub-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you execute the update query ?  What method do you call to execute it ? Do you call 'ExecuteUpdate' ?

And why do you think that you cannot execute an update query on a subclass using HQL ? AFAIK, it is possible.

Comment: Im using SpringDAOImpl the code:
Query namedQuery = session.getNamedQuery

And I get  
org.hibernate.QueryException: Update statements against joined or union subclasses not yet supported! 

Hibernate version 3.0.5

Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Yes, you're right, but in versions released later that  the one we're using (3.0.5).

Any of you know how to do that with 3.0.5? thanks